# strtotime not working

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to convert a date from a registration form (in the form 01/01/2011) to Y-m-d so that it can be stored in the database.

This is the code I have, pretty sure it worked before but now it has stopped working. Any ideas?

```
$dateformat = $_POST['dob'];
$correctformat = date('Y-m-d',strtortime($dateformat));
```

I have checked what `$_POST['dob']` is printing and it is correct, however the `$correctformat` is printing `1970-01-01` everytime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming in your script its `strtotime` and not `strtortime`?

Comment: It works for me: http://codepad.org/3NSbREH4

Comment: `01/01/2011` is ambiguous, are your dates in `m/d/Y` or `d/m/Y` format? The latter is not an [accepted date format](http://php.net/datetime.formats.date).

Comment: hi sorry it is in the form m/d/Y e.g. 30/05/2011

Comment: @nickb try a date such as 27/07/1985, not sure that will work?

Comment: @LucyGrainger It won't work, as you say, because that format is not valid for `strtotime`. Check some of the other answers to see how to change the date to a valid format (such as `m/d/Y`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currentformat = explode("/",$_POST['date']);
$newformat = $currentformat[2]."-".$currentformat[1]."-".$currentformat[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (note PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) instead of `strtotime` as `strtotime` accepts`m/d/Y` not `d/m/Y`

try :

```
$dateformat = $_POST['dob'];
$correctformat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateformat);
echo $correctformat->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I've tested this (as has @nickb in his comment) and it works fine with the format he has given. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: @Adam understood - perhaps the OPs problem is the `$_POST` or its format is d/m/Y

Comment: When I do this I get a catchable fatal error: object of class DateTime could not be converted to string. 

Also I will need the correct format date to be a variable so that I can use it to insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

.1. Can **you** tell, looking at the date, if it have month or day first? If you can't - **how it is supposed for the whatever program to determine the actual order?**

.2. this operation require **the very basic** string manipulations anyone have to learn if planning to be a PHP user:

```
$chunks = explode("/",$_POST['date']);
$date   = "$chunks[2]-$chunks[1]-$chunks[0]";
```

the order of chunks depends on the actual order of date parts

Comment: the actual format doesn't matter. you can set up whatever suits your needs. that's what programming for.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam says, there is no strtortime() it should be strtotime()

Did you really test it with the literal string '01/01/2011'? Some of us were born before 1970 - which may be causing some confusion (strtotime() generates a 32 bit Unix time).

(beware that strtotime interprets xx/xx/xx[xx] using the americal style of mm/dd/yy[yy] rather than the european convention of dd/mm/yy[yy]).

It works for me with the typo removed:

```
[colinm@dev-sensor ~]$ php -q t.php
2011-01-01
[colinm@dev-sensor ~]$ cat t.php
<?php

print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01/01/2011')) . "\n";
```

Comment: The minimum date generally is Fri, 13 Dec 1901 (min value of 32-bit signed int). However, some operating systems don't support this (Windows) so in that case the min would be the epoch.

Comment: sorry silly spelling mistake when I wrote the post. It did indeed say strtotime. I tested it with the date 27/07/1985 which didn't work. I understand that 01/01/2011 would work because the month and days could be confused!!